# Extending $scope

Tags: angularjs, scope

I'm trying to create some generally useful extensions to the $scope service in AngularJS:

(this code is defined outside of all controllers):

```
var ExtendScope = function ($scope) {

    // safeApply is a safe replacement for $apply
    $scope.safeApply = function (fn) {
        var phase = this.$root.$$phase;
        if (phase == '$apply' || phase == '$digest') {
            if (fn && (typeof (fn) === 'function')) {
                fn();
            }
        } else {
            this.$apply(fn);
        }
    };


    // alertOn is shorthand for event handlers that must just pop up a message
    $scope.alertOn = function (eventName, message) {
        $scope.on(eventname, function () { alert(message); });
    };
};
```

The first extension, `safeApply()`, works, but when I add `alertOn()` in the code above, my app doesn't work anymore even if `$scope.alertOn()` is not called. For the life of it I cannot see what I'm doing wrong. Is it so obvious that my mistake is hiding in plain sight?

Comment: [JSHint](http://jshint.com/) is your friend :) You specified the argument as `eventName`, but you are using it as `eventname` (lower case "n")!!!

Comment: Are you **sure** it isn't being called?  Are there any errors on the console?  Besides `eventName`/`eventname` mentioned by Nikos, isn't the proper method `$on` and not just `on`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by using `angular.extend` as follows:

```
"use strict";


// Safely apply changes to the $scope
// Call this instead of $scope.$apply();

var ExtendScope = function ($scope) {

        angular.extend($scope, {
            safeApply: function (fn) {
                var phase = this.$root.$$phase;
                if (phase == '$apply' || phase == '$digest') {
                    if (fn && (typeof (fn) === 'function')) {
                        fn();
                    }
                } else {
                    this.$apply(fn);
                }
            },

            alertOn: function (eventName, message) {
                this.$on(eventName, function () { alert(message); });
            }
        });
};
```

So now in my controllers I can simply add, for instance,

```
$scope.alertOn('save_succeeded', "Saved.");
```

and that works!

Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 1):

`on -> $on` as mentioned
and

```
this.$apply(fn);
```

it should be:

```
$scope.$apply(fn);
```

and:

```
var phase = this.$root.$$phase;
```

should be:

```
var phase = $scope.$root.$$phase; // or $scope.$$phase;
```

However, I would rewrite your code to use $timeout as angular's digest cycle isn't set in stone.

```
$timeout(function() {
   // code to by "apply'ed" to be digested next cycle
});
```

Comment: As the code is written, and as it is expected to be called, `this` *is* the `$scope`. So this will not make any difference in this question, although it is probably a good idea just to guard against unreasonable usage.